# SceneKit Swift - PhysicsBody not precise

Tags: swift, swift2, physics, scenekit

Hello,

I'm making a game with `SceneKit` in `Swift`.
In this game I have first `cube1` that is on a second `cube2` (that is the ground).

---

**PROBLEM 1**

The `cube1`'s `PhysicsBodyType` is `Kinematic`, while the second is `Static`.
I used `Kinematic` for the first cube because when I use `Dynamic`, the PhysicsBody is not precise as you can see on the image :

[image: game preview 1]

While when I use `Kinematic`, the `PhysicsBody` is right :

[image: game preview 2]

Do you know why the `PhysicsBody` is not precise ?

---

**PROBLEM 2**

I want to apply vertical force (y) to the `cube1` but it is impossible to do with `Kinematic` type, so I tried to use `SCNAction.moveBy` but the movement is not smooth.

Have you a solution for this ?

**CODE**

CUBE 1 :

```
let cubeGeometry = SCNBox(width: cubeSize, height: cubeSize, length: cubeSize, chamferRadius: 0.0)
cubeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor(netHex: 0xF1C40F)
cubeNode = SCNNode(geometry: cubeGeometry)
cubeNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)

let cubeShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: cubeGeometry, options: nil)
cubeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Dynamic, shape: cubeShape)
cubeNode.physicsBody?.angularVelocityFactor = SCNVector3(0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeNode)
```

CUBE 2 :

```
for index in 0...10 {

    let cubeGeometry = SCNBox(width: cubeSize, height: cubeSize, length: cubeSize, chamferRadius: 0.0)

    let randomColor = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(colorsArray.count)))

    cubeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = colorsArray[randomColor]

    let cubeGround = SCNNode(geometry: cubeGeometry)
    cubeGround.position = SCNVector3(x: 0.0, y: -Float(cubeSize), z: Float(index) * -Float(cubeSize))
    cubeGround.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: SCNPhysicsBodyType.Static, shape: SCNPhysicsShape(node: cubeGround, options: nil))
    cubeGround.physicsBody?.angularVelocityFactor = SCNVector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cubeGround)
```

}